# Cannot Create Secure SSL/TLS Channel Error While Performing Facebook C# SDK GET Operation

Tags: c#, .net, https, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-javascript-sdk

After testing code locally on Windows 7/IIS7.5, we've deployed this code to a Windows 2003/IIS6 production environment and are receiving the dreaded "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error.

I've added every possible ServicePointManager line of code and to no avail:

> ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = true;
>       ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
>       ServicePointManager.CheckCertificateRevocationList = true;
>       ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit =        ServicePointManager.DefaultPersistentConnectionLimit;
>       ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
>       ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

This all comes about while using the latest Facebook C# SDK and attempting to perform a GET operation.

By tracing, I'm able to see that the Facebook Token is being passed correctly, but can't figure out anything else.

Any ideas?  I've tried every solution I can find but can't seem to figure out anything that works.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like it may be a Facebook issue: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/367369176650486?browse=search_4fd7d1bd3dc908653044192

Comment: From today my application has this problem with Facebook. It works on my development computer but when I upload it to the server then it does not work. It looks like to be a Facebook + Host Server problem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace calls to graph.facebook.com with graph.beta.facebook.com and you will be operational again it worked for us. Hope Facebook will fix this soon.